# ViewWillAppear of ParentViewController not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, viewwillappear

I am trying to implement a custom UIActionSheet(made up of a ViewController)
I have added a View Controller as a subView to the navigationcontroller of my rootView

```
- (IBAction)ShowMenu:(id)sender
{
   [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.menuViewController.view];
   [self.menuViewController setTest:YES];
   [self.menuViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

here MenuViewController has a tableview which has few options to select. After selecting I am opening those respective ViewControllers. Suppose I clicked on menu1 and then opened menu1ViewController and it works fine. Now when I close this viewController, I am calling dismissViewController.

and in menuViewController I have written the code to animate by menuviewController to bottom and it works fine.

but the parent of MenuView is TestViewController inside which the functions viewdidAppear is not called when menuviewController animates down.

and thats my problem,

I am using this code to animate by menuViewController to bottom

```
- (void) slideOut {


  [UIView beginAnimations:@"removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation" context:nil];

    // Set delegate and selector to remove from superview when animation completes
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    // Move this view to bottom of superview
    CGRect frame = self.menusheet.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.menusheet.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

// Method called when removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation's animation completes
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation"]) {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

MenuViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(m_test)
    {
        [self slideIn];
        m_test = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        [self slideOut];       
    }

}
```

Comment: please format the code so others can understand...

Comment: `MenuViewController -viewWillApper:, -viewdidAppear:` code please ?

Comment: It looks like you TestViewController is actually stays in the view hierarchy (i.e. it is visible), so no viewWillAppear will be called. From the docs: viewWillAppear ["Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy"(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:)

Comment: So how to solve this issue

Comment: You can manually call the viewWillAppear when animation stops, or extract the part of functionality from TestViewController's viewWillAppear into separate method and call it. BTW block animations using UIView [animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:) are more handy.

Comment: I cannot declare an instance of my testViewController in menuViewController, I get errors

Comment: @Ranjit Thanks, now let's figure out what is the problem exactly. You are saying `viewWillApper` at title but `viewDidAppear` at question. So which one is not called (please add `viewdidAppear` code as well) for which class ? Please clarify what you mean by `TestViewController` being the "parent", is it a superclass or it's view is a parent view of `MenuViewController` view ?

Comment: @A-Live  both viewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear of TestViewController is not called when the menuviewController animates down and Testviewcontroller is paren view of MenuViewController

Comment: Not a best solution but why don't you just call viewWillAppear manually like:
`- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

if ([animationID 
isEqualToString:@"removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation"]) {
        [self.parentViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }

}`

The parentViewController is just UIViewController*, it is available if you use addChildViewController.

Comment: I tried it is not called

Comment: hey @SergiySalyuk, check my first function showMenu, I have added a subView to navigationController.view

Comment: Ah, I see. Then if you can't use TestViewController as a parent, you can use either custom delegate to notify your TestViewController (when menu is closed) OR you can pass block that contains viewWillAppear call as a property to your MenuViewController (in ShowMenu).

Comment: Adding a delegate , will let you know the status

Comment: Hi @SergiySalyuk, I am not able to add a delegate also, because menuViewController is added as a property to TestViewController and also as IBOUTLET. How to pass a block that contains viewWillAppear call as a property to MenuViewController ?

Comment: `typedef void (^PostAnimationActions)();
@interface MenuViewController
...
@property(nonatomic, copy) PostAnimationActions postAnimationActions;
...
(void) animationDidStop...
postAnimationActions();
...
`
And in the ShowMenu add something like:
`self.menuViewController.postAnimationActions = ^{[self viewWillAppear:YES];};`

Comment: hi @SergiySalyuk  how you have added postAnimationActions() in -(void) animationDidStop?

Comment: Hey this will also not work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21006/discussion-between-sergiy-salyuk-and-ranjit)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, `-[UIViewController viewWillAppear]` and `-[UIViewController viewDidAppear]` would only be called where the callee is added into the view controllers hierarchy by those container-like controllers, like a navigation controller, a tab bar controller.

It would not be called if you just add the view by calling `addSubview:` in your code. [See also](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html).

You could call `-viewWillAppear` and `-viewDidAppear` where appropriate, programmatically in your code, before and after you called `addSubview:` with or without animations.

Comment: thanks for reply, so how should I solve this and what wrong I have done here

Comment: @Ranjit adding and animating subview to `TestViewController` view doesn't call viewWillAppear, nor viewDidAppear, nor viewWillDisappear, nor viewDidDisappear of `TestViewController`. You can call them (or any other methods you wish to prepare) manually.